# Why is this Batch Script not echoing to files?

Tags: windows, batch, script

```
REM. > "disk\usr\%3.stf"
echo "%~2" >> "disk\usr\%3.stf"
exit
```

Above should print "nothing" (Essentially creating a empty .stf file), then should print User Parameter 2 (without quotes) to that file. It shows that it worked, but I see no file of that name in the directory.

Comment: Your `exit` might prevent you from seeing errors. Try putting in a `pause` to see if it's giving you an error message. Are you sure the script is running in the correct folder?

Comment: @Worthwelle I think I found the issue.. my program is called "print", which is the name of a cmd file named print.exe. AND im using a bat-to-exe converter which makes it a exe, so cmd is thinking that MY print.exe is their SYSTEM .exe

Comment: Glad to hear that you resolved the problem on your own! Please keep in mind that you can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and accept it accordingly.